# RoundtripKind mode xml serialize

Tags: c#, datetime, xml-serialization

I am using the code below in order to serialize Topology class to xml:

```
public static bool WriteTopologyFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Topology));
        using (StreamWriter reader = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(reader, Runtime.Topology);
        }
        return true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Log.WriteEventLog(ex, EventLogEntryType.Error);
     }
     return false;
}
```

In Topology class, there are some DateTime fields and i want to serialize these DateTime fields in

```
System.Xml.XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind
```

mode. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[XmlIgnore]
public DateTime Time { get; set; }

[XmlElement("Time")]
public string strTime
{
        get { return Time.ToString("o"); }
        set { Time = DateTime.Parse(value); }
}
```